# SQL Table Custom AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have to create a particular system of reviews in which I should do a lot of AVG in my query, so I want to ask if it's possible to create a table in SQL in which I have these Averages automatically updated?

Mysql 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to do this:

- You can create a "view", which is like a table, except that its records come from a SQL query (usually derived from other tables) rather than being stored directly. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html.
- You can create a "trigger", which is procedural code that runs whenever a specified table is modified in a specified way. In your case, you would create a trigger that runs whenever one table is modified, and that re-generates the secondary table. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html.